# Dynamically change the wsdl endpoint URL based on the environment through some property config file

Tags: java

How to replace the soap:address location, I want to dynamically replace the soap:address location in the WSDL based on the environment (dev, test, production) without changing the WSDL.

If I run my code to DEV, Test or Prod I should be able to dynamically replace the soap:address location based on the hostname, meaning I plan to load the URL from a properties file?

Comment: What web service library are you using?